# Loop function over list

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to divide element 1 of a list by element 2; element 2 by element 3, and so on. What is the best way of doing this?

I have tried

```
f = #1/#2 &
```

Have a feeling I might have to use `Do`, or `Reap` / `Sow` but don't have any programming background, so coming unstuck.

Comment: `Ratios` is almost your friend :)

Comment: @ Öskå - thanks - indeed it is!

Comment: `1/# & /@ Ratios@list` is even more your friend ;o)

Comment: @Öskå, or maybe just `1/Ratios@list`

Comment: Should the last element be divided by the first one, or just not taken into consideration? Because that's the case with @SimonWoods solution.

Comment: @SimonWoods, no no no, you are totally wrong. :D

Comment: Completing OP's form: `f = (#1/#2 &) @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Operations on adjacent pairs of elements comes up often in [list-manipulation](/questions/tagged/list-manipulation), although I can't recall a specific question on this. Sometimes you get lucky with a built in function like `Ratios` or `Differences` that does exactly what you want. But what if there isn't a built-in function for your specific need?

The idiom you need to remember that will be useful for any arbitrary function (not just division or subtraction) is to use `Most` and `Rest`:

```
list = Range@10;
Most@list/Rest@list    
(* {1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, 6/7, 7/8, 8/9, 9/10} *)
```

Comment: Worth to mention that `Partition[list,2,1]` may be useful but in this case it is longer. Maybe the title can be changed so it will become a refference Q&A for operations on adjacent elements?

Answer (score 5):

Just for comparison:

```
list = Range[1000];

Do[ Divide @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]                     , {1000}] // Timing // First
Do[ 1/Ratios@list                                        , {1000}] // Timing // First
Do[ Most@list/Rest@list                                  , {1000}] // Timing // First
Do[ #/#2 & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]                     , {1000}] // Timing // First
Do[ Developer`PartitionMap[Divide @@ # &, list, 2, 1]    , {1000}] // Timing // First
Do[ #[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ Partition[list, 2, 1]             , {1000}] // Timing // First
Do[ Developer`PartitionMap[#[[1]]/#[[2]] &, list, 2, 1]  , {1000}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.045207
> 1.154407
> 0.982806
> 2.402415
> 3.151220
> 4.196427
> 4.087226
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
Most[#1/#2] &[list, RotateLeft[list]]
```